# Calling Angular Controller Function from Browser Console

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to call AngularJS controller function from console (Chrome Developer Tools console)?

e.g.

```
app.controller('AddCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {



    $scope.save = function(){
        // do stuff here - call it from console
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, you just need to use `angular.element` to get an element that's within the scope of your controller:

```
angular.element("yourElement").scope().save();
```

Comment: what is "yourElement" - controller?

Comment: It's an element that is within the controllers scope, so `<body ng-controller="yourController"><div id="someElem"></div></body>` - the div with ID `someElem` is within the scope, so you can do: `angular.element("someElem").scope()` - see the guide for more: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: hm...my body has no `ng-controller` attribute. will the same rule apply when using `ng-view`?

Comment: Where is your controller defined?

Comment: in config, `.when("/add", { controller: "AddCtrl", templateUrl: "views/add.html"
    })`

Comment: Hmm..not sure, try targeting an element within that view.

Comment: angular.element(document.querySelector('#id'))

Comment: You could also wrap that in a function and call the function, but either way this answer is correct.

Answer (score 25):

Open the browsers developer console. Inspect the element where the controller gets injected. Execute the following:

```
angular.element($0).scope().save()
```

$0 is the element you are currently selecting in the developer console elements panel.

Answer (score 11):

If you are only using angular and NOT using jquery you can do something like `angular.element(document.getElementById('yourElement')).scope().save();`

If you are using BOTH angular and jquery, you can do `angular.element($('#yourElement')).scope().save();` assuming the the id attribute of your element is set like this `<div id=yourElement></div>`

**VERY IMPORTANT** But as [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709373/angularjs-how-to-call-controller-function-from-outside-of-controller-component) if the function you are calling from the console does anything such that you wish the changes to show up in the view then you have to pass them through `$apply()` like this

```
var scope = angular.element($('#story')).scope();
scope.$apply(function(){
  scope.showNextScene();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the very important last part saved me!

Comment: @legas Angular has silly quirks. Takes ages to get past them sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can load a **Chrome Extension** for developers called **[AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en-US)**.

It will add an AngularJS tab to the developer console.

Selecting an element in your page, if it has a $scope, it will show in the "**Elements**" right hand pane, under the "**$scope**" tab.

Comment: As mentioned by others If jQuery is available, angular.element is just an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Chrome inspector click on the element which is scope related
   to controller where you want to execute.
2. Type angular.element($0).scope().nameYourFunctionInScope();
3. Execute

Comment: Type it where ? ?

Comment: @LachezarRaychev in the console