# Call Angular Controller Function from Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, controller

How can I call a controller's function from my browser's console, when I do not use the `$scope` syntax for my functions but the `controller as` syntax. There is no `ng-controller` injected so I cannot use the method proposed at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795628/calling-angular-controller-function-from-browser-console). I use the `$stateProvider` of `ui-router` to set my controller to a view like so:

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  template: ...,
  controller: 'ContactsCtrl as contact'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By Browser I am assuming you mean your HTML code.
How are the scope functions defined within your controller definition?

Incase you are using a virtual model as in

```
function ContactsCtrl(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.scopeFn = function(){
    //Do sumthin
  }
}
```

Then you can just do this from the html :

```
<button ng-click="contact.scopeFn()" />
```

**Update** : By browser's JS if you mean as in like within `<script>` tag then do,

```
function ContactsCtrl(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.scopeFn = function(){
    //Do sumthin
  }
  window.globalFn = vm.scopeFn;

}
```

And then call it from the browser as :

```
<script>
  //on some event :
  window.globalFn();
</script>
```

I hope this helps. Although I wouldn't advice exposing a controller function outside the angular app module. But, if you want temporary fix go ahead and use this approach.

Comment: I mean the browser's javascript console

Comment: Look at the update to the answer. I hope this is what you want.