# How to execute the constructor of an Angular controller after registration (i.e. from console)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, google-chrome-devtools

after trying the entire day here I am...

Angularjs newbie, though decent knowledge in js, I believe for some of you this question should be a no-brainer.

Suppose we have the following angular mini app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <h1 ng-click="toggle()">{{firstname}}</h1>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.firstname = "adam";
            $scope.toggle = function() {
                $scope.firstname = "eva";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to register further controller afterwards (i.e. from the console), as follows:

```
// ought to overwrite the behaviour of the old one
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "adam";
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.firstname= $scope.firstname == 'adam' ? 'eva' : 'adam';
    }
});
```

How on earth do I invoke programmatically the constructor of the latter controller in order to get new behaviour for the toggle function (preferable from the console)???

**Edit**

Accessing the scope of the controller and assign `toogle` to the new function does not really help in case the function refers to variables declared inside the constructor but outside the functions body.

Comment: This seems similar, inspect your dom then you should just be able to use a selector and run the toggle function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795628/calling-angular-controller-function-from-browser-console

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I am not referring to the scope access of a controller. I am wondering how the constructor gets executed so that ```$scope.toggle``` is assigned to the new function. I've seen that post before btw.

Comment: I was playing around with this: `angular.element(document.querySelector('.my-class')).scope().toggle = function () { alert('ok'); }` where `my-class` would be a class for your `<h1>` tag and this overrides the toggle functionality, but I don't know if that's what you were looking for

Comment: Please check my edits. My goal actually is to execute the constructor of the snd controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to assign the controller's constructor to a variable:

```
var ctrl = function($scope, t) {
    $scope.firstname = "adam";
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.firstname= $scope.firstname == 'adam' ? 'eva' : 'adam';    
    }
    console.log("Controller was Instantiated!!!");
};
```

and then instantiate that using the injector as follows:

```
var injector = angular.element($0).injector();
injector.instantiate(ctrl, { 
    $scope: injector.get("$rootScope"),
    t: injector.get("t")
});
```

(Assuming the service `t` has already been registered.)

Comment: ```angular.element($0).inject()``` 

VM68:1 Uncaught TypeError: angular.element(...).inject is not a function     at <anonymous>:1:21

Comment: Try `angular.element($0).injector()` instead.

Comment: Sorry, my fault... However I still don't know how to inject methods that profits from the execution environment of a constructor with dependencies. Just think of something like:  ```app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope','d', function($scope,d) { $scope.toggle = function () {d.doSomething();} } ])```

Comment: You have to inject these manually yourself using the injector's `get()` method. I've updated my answer as an example.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks. Unfortunately, I cannot give you more than one upvote...

Comment: Haha, no problem, pleased it helped anyway.