# How to call an angular 6 function from browser console?

Tags: angular6

I want to call a function that is inside a component from the browser console.
I want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795628/calling-angular-controller-function-from-browser-console)
but equivalent to angular 6.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can check by below method..

on your google chrome console, you can run below command

```
ng.probe($0).componentInstance.<name of function you want to run from component.ts file>
```

You can check the output.

Do let me know if you need further clarification.

**Please check [reference](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/debugging-angular2-console/) for better understanding.**