# How to call angular8 component's function on webview?

Tags: angular

My environment is webview, and I want to call Angular's function from Java, so I have to find out the function. How can I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a service function from browser console in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212288/call-a-service-function-from-browser-console-in-angular-6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the JavaScript function’s return value, you need to use the evaluateJavascript method:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:myTestFunction();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            // Do what you want with the return value
        }
    });
```

## 1) Calling Method of Java application from Angular2+ application:-

Suppose, `JavaFunction.SomeJavaMethod()` is defined in Java app then,

## .ts

```
 let data = {
    'key' : 2
    }
    JavaFunction.SomeJavaMethod(data);// call from angular
```

## 2) Calling Angular method from webview/JavaApplication:-

## index.html

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         // data send from webview java app...call from java app
        function updateFromJAVAapp(data) {
            window['componentRef'].zone.run(() => {
                window['componentRef'].component.updateFromMyJavaApp(data);
            });
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

## .ts

```
 constructor(
        private zone: NgZone
    ) {
        window['componentRef'] = {
            zone: this.zone,
            componentFn: (value) => this.updateFromMyJavaApp(value),
            component: this
        };
    }

    updateFromMyJavaApp(data) {
        console.log( JSON.stringify(data)); <=== data passed from java app webview
    }
```

## Refer Link:-

https://www.tanelikorri.com/tutorial/android/communication-between-application-and-webview/

http://shripalsoni.com/blog/nativescript-webview-native-bi-directional-communication/

Answer (score 1):

On browser, click on the html tag represents `Component` you want to find.

[image]

Then `ng.probe($0).componentInstance`

[image]

Comment: But ng.probe($0) is null !

Comment: When click on a HTML tags, `$0` will be changed to its `Element` and `ng.probe($0)` is not null.

Comment: Yes, I click the HTML tags, and $0 change to the element. But...still null. Besides I wanted to avoid the click.

Comment: Have you used debugMode in Angular? Because it's only available in development not production.

Comment: In fact, my environment is webview. I want to call Angular's function from Java, so I have to find out the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
ngOnInit{
 (window as any).name_visible_from_console = this.class_function.bind(this);
}
```

i think it's good to clear it in ngOnDestory

you also need to use ApplicationRef#tick in called method, cause angular won't update view