# Accessing class method from console in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to call the class method through console which intern accesses the class variable and then it reflects on the HTML.
I Referred [Call a service function from browser console in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212288/call-a-service-function-from-browser-console-in-angular-6) but I was unable to access this keyword.

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'calender-app';
    timeslot: any =  [];

    constructor(){
      window['plotEvent'] = this.plotEvent;
    }
  
    plotEvent(events: Calender[]): void{
    // not able to access this.timeslot when I call it from browser's console.
    this.timeslot.push(...events); // getting error as can't read property timeslot of undefined.
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. The link you have posted should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to access a typescript method on the browsers console.

You can make the entire angular `component.ts`'s variables, methods etc. available to access in the browser console by adding `OnInit` or in the `constructor` the following:

Let's say you are trying to access a method within the `AppComponent`, you go.

```
OnInit() {
    window['AppComponent'] = this;
}
```

Or:

```
constructor() {
    window['AppComponent'] = this;
}
```

The same works in services too.

Then in the console you go:
`AppComponent.myMethod()`

Comment: This updated the timeslot but the HTML did not reflect the changes.

Comment: I don't think that you can refresh the dom with new content. once it was loaded by accessing the console.

Comment: You can try in `OnInit` to call `this.plot(events)` to see the HTML changes