# how to trigger typescript funtion from javascript function in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a task where I have an event listener window.addEventListener which is in javascript, based on event data I want to trigger a function of typescript and pass the data to that function. the point I am not getting is how to call typescript function in javascript. I have tried different things like a global variable, returning a value from js function but didn't work for me.

```
ngOnInit() {
  (function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log("Rece new Call event ibrahim " + JSON.stringify(event.data));
        let obj: any = JSON.stringify(event.data)
        obj = JSON.parse(obj);
        console.log(obj)
        if (obj.EventType === "handleContactIncoming") {
        
          var num = obj.Number
         // here i want to trigger Typescript function and pass this num to that function.
            
        }
        else if (event.data === "endCall") {
     //     return "No"
          // var dbBtn = document.getElementById("db");
          // dbBtn.click();
        }
        // $('.sidebar-menu').tree();
      });
     
    });
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling properly TypeScript code from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427722/calling-properly-typescript-code-from-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing class method from console in angular typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008382/accessing-class-method-from-console-in-angular-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference when calling function from TS or JS. Finally there's always only JS in the browser, TS exists only in source code.

Also your code is a bit messy. There's no need to use jQuery inside angular (with an exception when you want to use some plugins or custom controls).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

is also redundant, if angular works the document is for sure ready.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite messy and breaks separation of concerns. You should not use jQuery inside Angular. The injectable [EventManager](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/EventManager) provides functionality for setting events on the `window` or `document` objects.

```js
constructor(private readonly eventManager: EventManager) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.eventManager.addGlobalEventListener(target, event, () => {
    this.hello();
  });
}

hello(): void {
  console.log('Hello World!');
}
```