# How to call a service from browser console for debugging?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular11

I would like to call my `ApiService` from a browser console.

I tried what explained in [Call a service function from browser console in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212288/call-a-service-function-from-browser-console-in-angular-6):

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {window['myService'] = this}
```

Which is causing compiling error:

```
Error: ../services/api.service.ts:12:49 - error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

12   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {window['ApiService'] = this; }
```

I also tried to run this from console:

```js
angular.element(document).injector().get('ApiService');
```

But angular dependencies do not seem to be loaded as I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:1
```

Any clue to progress on this topic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a service function from browser console in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212288/call-a-service-function-from-browser-console-in-angular-6)

Comment: @yehonatanyehezkel, I have already tried what explained in this post, and I get the error described in my question. I wish I could have it work

Comment: Its working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aajstl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts @blondelg

Comment: Just in case, did you copy paste the answer ? Try to do this in the console `console.log(window['myService'])`. Because in your question you defined the global variable in `window['myService']` and not `window['ApiService']`