# Call controller function from outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to access (call and/or modify) the scope of a controller from outside of it.
Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737459/608068) I managed to access the scope, but the data binding doesn't kick in...

Take this as example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyhaomk1/2/)).

```js
angular.module("App", []).controller("Test", function($scope)
{
    $scope.list = ["added on initialization"];

    $scope.add = function(item)
    {
        $scope.list.push(item);
    };
});

var addFromOutside = function()
{
    angular
        .element(document.getElementById("TestController"))
        .scope()
        .add('added from outside');
};
```

```html
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Test" id="TestController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>

    <button ng-click="add('added from inside')">Add from inside</button>
</div>

<button onclick="addFromOutside()">Add from outside</button>
```

If you click in the "**Add from inside**" button it works like expected.
But if you click in the "**Add from outside**" button nothing happens until you click in the "**Add from inside**" button...

Is there anyway to do this and the have data binding working?

Comment: why do you want to call it from outside? I mean you can use `ng-controller` multiple times if you need to

Comment: yeah, just wrap that button with `<div ng-controller="Test"></div>`

Comment: @JohnyStark, saddly, a controller isn't a singleton... This means that each call to `ng-controller` creates another instance of it, so, the properties aren't shared between instances. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add

```
scope.$apply()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o2b0bdbr/
you are outside of angulars digest cycle so you need to let him know that something happen to on of his scopes

Comment: Simple and effective... Thanks.

Comment: I have to wait a couple of minutes to accept it, but I will... =]