# How to access an Angular controller from the main page when using ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access an Angular controller from outside of the controller component.

This is answered well in this question: [AngularJS. How to call controller function from outside of controller component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709373/angularjs-how-to-call-controller-function-from-outside-of-controller-component)

However, what if I am using ngRoute with code like this:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
        controller: 'secondController'
    })

});
```

So the index page only has this tag: `<div ng-view></div>`.

Is there a way I can access the controller that is currently in the ng-view?

(I tried to locate `mainController` on the index page, but for:

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("mainController")).scope();
```

scope is undefined.)

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424910/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-js-function

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe there is a better way to do what you want

Comment: @RenanLopesFerreira: I want to resize elements in the view (associated with the current controller) when window resize event occurs.

Comment: You should use directives for that