# function in $(document).ready() not finding body element of DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am writing an AngularJS web app and have a function outside of any scope that needs to call a function inside of a scope. I call the function and follow the instructions given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737459/5759077) answer.

```
function returnDest(callback) {
$(document).ready(angular.element(document.getElementById('body')).scope().getTask(function() {
    if(callback) {
        callback(locationInfo);
    }
}));
}
```

It works often, but sometimes the function does not successfully run. A debugger gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTask' of undefined
```

I do not know why the function is being called on undefined when $(document).ready should have the function fire only after the DOM has been loaded. The same error pops up if I use $(window).load(). What can I do to ensure this function runs successfully?

For reference, here is the line in the HTML file where the 'body' element is defined

```
<body style="background-color:#e6e8f3" ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller" id="body">
```

Comment: that is not how you use ready... It expects a function and you just are running JavaScript in it...

Comment: out of curiosity...where are you using this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `.ready` incorrectly. The moment you call `returnDest`, which is happening before the DOM is ready, it tries to get an element with the ID of `body`. Since it's not loaded, `body` can't be accessed. Instead, omit the `body` ID and use it like this:

```
function returnDest(callback) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    angular.element(document.body).scope().getTask(function() {
      if (callback) {
        callback(locationInfo); // Not sure where locationInfo is coming from
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, this worked perfectly for what I needed. Trying to understand this further though, I understand that the main reason why the code I posted didn't work was because I didn't wrap the call to getTask inside a function. Does it make any difference whether I use document.body, or document.getElementById('body')?

Comment: @jcharch The only real difference is you don't have to give the body an ID and it's shorter to write ;)

Answer (score 2):

`$(document).ready` should be outside of your function:

```
$(document).ready(function returnDest(callback) {
angular.element(document.getElementById('body')).scope().getTask(function() {
    if(callback) {
        callback(locationInfo);
    }
})});
```

Comment: that changes the scope of  `returnDest` ,,,, doubt that was intended.

Answer (score 0):

`angular.element` returns a jQuery object.

`ready()` expects the argument you pass it to be **a function** that it will call when the document is ready.

It sounds like you need to wrap everything you are trying to pass to `ready` in `function () { ... }`.