# Angular JS access scope from outside of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

So I've just tried making the change from plain JS to angular and I'm wondering how I would access my controllers scope from another .js file.  I've looked around and I've tried a couple of ways but no luck.

I've found similar questions such as below such as

[AngularJS. How to call controller function from outside of controller component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709373/angularjs-how-to-call-controller-function-from-outside-of-controller-component)

[AngularJS access scope from outside js function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424910/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-js-function)

I'm not looking to make any changes to a scope value, rather just use a function from within the scope. Any ideas on how I'd go about calling the function from the controllers scope in another .js file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call it like this: 
For example html:

```
<div ng-app>
<div id="outer" ng-controller="MsgCtrl">
    You are {{msg}}
</div>
<div onclick="change()">click me</div>
```

And JS:

```
    function MsgCtrl($scope) 
{
    $scope.msg = "great";
}

function change()
{
    //alert("a");
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('outer')).scope();
    console.log(scope);
    //scope.msg = 'Superhero';
}
```

As you can see you need to **get by ID**, not controller's name.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apimenov93/brbhnpcg/1/)

Comment: Hey Alexey, I came across that solution earlier this evening yet I keep getting an error, I've edited the question to give some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Put an id to tag where you apply ng-controller, then getting scope would be as simple as this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController id="myScope">
</div>
..
var myScope = angular.element(myScope);
myScope.runSomeFn();
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikishkinvv/wuucd8yd/)

Comment: Within another JavaScript file e.g file name is . app.js ? My understanding of the DIV tag is that it's purely within HTML.

Comment: It doesn't matter where to put call to scope, if this in the same file with div or in another. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nikishkinvv/wuucd8yd/) I made an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $controller service to instantiate a controller inside any other Js (the file you want to extend with this function. I will use another controller for this example):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('fileCreateController',[function(){
  
  this.action = 'Initial value';
  
  this.fileCreate = function(value){
    
    console.log('ACTION');
    
    this.action = value;
    
  }
  
}]);

app.controller('anyController', ['$controller', function($controller){
  this.valueToSend =  'Changed value from fileCreateController';
  angular.extend(this, $controller('fileCreateController'));
  
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="anyController as vm">
    <button name="button" ng-click="vm.fileCreate(vm.valueToSend)">Click me</button>
   <p>{{vm.action}}</p>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if you can, you should create a Service with the function you want to share, and inject the service wherever you want to use this function.

Comment: I've been playing around with it since earlier and was wondering would it be possible to do it in the reverse direction i.e. pass an object/variable over to the controller ? The difficult thing with the suggestion is due to cordova I'm unable to use _any_ HTML elements in certain parts.

Comment: Sure, you can send an objec or any other value as parameter from the function in the view. Something like this: vm.fileCreate(OBJECT/VARIABLE);

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this.

```
<script>
var myConEle = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=myController]');
var $scope = angular.element(myConEle).scope();
</script>

<div ng-controller="myController"> 

</div>
```