# Get angular controller from script tag

Tags: angularjs

**UPDATE**: This is an ["X Y problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The way I was trying to do it is answered [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709373/angularjs-how-to-call-controller-function-from-outside-of-controller-component/#answer-16737459) to a question that's an exact duplicate. However, my actual goal is best reached using [`ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) rather than reinventing a kludgey fake one-way binding mechanism by hand.

--

In the below code, `controller` isn't defined in the `ready()` callback. I didn't really think it would be.

The intent here is for the controller to "raise an event" whenever its title changes (easy), and have the HTML update `document.title` when that happens. The question is, is there any way for the HTML to get its hands on the controller to do that?

```
<html 
      ng-app="foo" 
      ng-controller="FooController as controller"
      >
<head>
    <title>Default Title</title>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="foo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.element(window.document.body).ready(
            function () {
                //  This does get called
                //alert('test');

                //  controller isn't defined, not too surprisingly. 
                controller.titleChanged = function (title) {
                    //alert(title)
                    document.title = title;
                };
            });
    </script>
</head>
```

I can set the title like this:

```
<title>{{controller.title}}</title>
```

...but then I see `{{controller.title}}` in my browser history instead of a meaningful title, and as I understand it that's also what a search engine would see.

Of course I can have the controller assign the new title to `document.title`, and for now that's what I'm doing, but I prefer to keep controllers ignorant of views.

Comment: try `<title ng-bind="controller.title"></title>`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709373/angularjs-how-to-call-controller-function-from-outside-of-controller-component/#answer-16737459) might be the answer to your problem.

Comment: @IhorKorotenko That's perfect. If you want to put that in as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS. How to call controller function from outside of controller component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709373/angularjs-how-to-call-controller-function-from-outside-of-controller-component)

Comment: @Korte Thank you, that's an exact duplicate. I just voted to close as a duplicate, in fact.

Comment: OK, added as answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of interpolation use `ng-bind` directive.