# Calling angular function inside controller from Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

I have a submitDetails function inside controller in app.js file and I want to call it from a javascript function. But its throwing error
Error: Submit Details is undefined

```js
clickApply: function(e) {
            
            console.log("hi&hello");
            
                    angular.element('#span').scope().submitDetails();
               
            this.hide();
            this.element.trigger('apply.daterangepicker', this);

        }
```

```js
$rootScope.submitDetails=function()
```

Comment: can you pls elaborate pls add html and js code in a working format

Comment: See This:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709373/angularjs-how-to-call-controller-function-from-outside-of-controller-component

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as below

**JS**

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sayHello = function() {
      $scope.msg = 'Hello';
    }
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("btn")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.sayHello();
    });
  }, 2000)
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl' id='ctrl'>
      {{msg}}
      <button id='btn' ng-click='sayHello()'>
        Go
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Hope this will help you [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dr0xyhvk/)

Comment: you're mixing vanilla js and angularjs. And you're manipulating DOM from controller

Comment: @Gonzalo.- no no its just to access controller method from out side of it.